# Azure Application Insights - values within objects

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get my head around writing queries in Azure Application Insights which is capturing interactions with a bot built using Azure Bot Framework.

I have a table with headings such as `timestamp`, `name`, `customDimensions`, `customDimensions` and within `customDimensions` are objects such as

`{
  "conversationData": "{}",
  "privateConversationData": "{\"nameForm\":{\"NAME\":\"foo\",\"ICCID\":\"12121212121212121212\"}}",
  "userData": "{}",
  "conversationId": "878fhiee1k33j5ci",
  "userId": "default-user",
  "metrics": "92.25833"
}`

I can write queries easily to select items by name for example
`customEvents 
| where name contains "Activity"`

but how do I select based on keys within objects such as those within `privateConversationData` above?

For example `"privateConversationData": "{\"nameForm\":{\"NAME\":\"foo\",\"ICCID\":\"12121212121212121212\"}}",` refers to one dialog called nameForm, how would I write a query to show the number of times the nameForm was used?  Or a query that included the other kinds of dialog (e.g. not just nameForm, but fooForm, barForm) and a count of the times they were used?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'customDimensions' property is a dynamic type and therefore can be treated as a JSON document.

For example - to get the number of times nameForm was used in the last day:

```
customEvents
| extend conversationData = customDimensions["privateConversationData"]
| where timestamp > ago(1d) and isnotempty(conversationData) and conversationData contains "{\\\"nameForm\\\""
| count
```

Getting the different dialogs count will be trickier, but possible by parsing the customDimensions JSON document using the [parse operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#parse-operator):

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(1d) 
| parse customDimensions with * "privateConversationData\": \"{\\\"" dialogKind "\\\":{\\\"NAME\\\"" *
| where isnotempty(dialogKind) and isnotnull(dialogKind)
| summarize count() by dialogKind
```

You can read the [Analytics Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference) to learn more about the language.

Comment: Thanks @yonisha.  This is looking promising but not quite right at the moment.  For example the first query returns no results.  However if I run `customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(20d) and isnotempty(customDimensions.privateConversationData)`  then I can see the results but adding `.formName` e.g. `.nameForm` to the results results in no records returned.  Similarly the second query seems to return results that do not contain `privateConversationData` (or that pattern that it is looking for)

Comment: thanks!  I've changed first query to `customEvents
| extend conversationData = customDimensions["privateConversationData"]
| where timestamp > ago(20d) and isnotempty(conversationData) and conversationData contains "nameForm"
| count` - using `contains` rather than `starstwith` works.    I'm not having any luck with the second query however, no records matched.  If I run the query without `and isnotnull(dialogKind)` I get a single column with a count value (there are more dialogs that just one so should be multiple columns? ). Adding `and isnotnull(dialogKind)` returns no matches

Comment: fixed. anyway - it is just a matter of how to parse the string within your customDimensions column